# HTML form using gmail without backend?

Tags: html, forms, api, gmail

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to use GMAIL in an HTML contact form without a backend, like formspree ie. Does GMAIL give an API key for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I made a little Heroku app for doing this, it requires no login and completely free without any asterisks. Best for static sites!

Requirements:

- All `inputs` must have a `name` property,
- The `action` property must be "http://form-delivr.herokuapp.com/handler/yourEmailAddress",
- The `method` property must be `post`,

If anyone submits the form, the data will be mailed back to the email address you provided in the action property!

Example:

```html
<form action="http://form-delivr.herokuapp.com/handler/tony@mail.com" method="post">
    <h4>Username:</h4>
    <input name="username">
    <h4>Email:</h4>
    <input type="email", name="email">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note: I will be changing on this so stay tuned or your form may stop working suddenly if you use this :(